# how to handle the image location in css if using grails asset-pipeline plugin?

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-plugin

the jquery.flipcountdown.css file is:

```
.xdsoft_flipcountdown.xdsoft_size_lg >.xdsoft_digit{
width:53px; 
height:76px;
background-image:url(./img/digit-lg.png);
}
```

the directory structure is

```
+flipcountdown-master
 + img
   - digit-lg.png
 - jquery.flipcountdown.css
```

the question is: how to use asset-pipeline in this case.

1: put the css under the assets/stylesheets, and put the img folder under the assets/images folder ? CAN IT WORK ?

2: put the css file and the img folder all to the assets/stylesheets folder, i am pretty sure it can work, but the asset-pipeline can gzip it?

i'm not good at js/css, and i spent much time to read the Asset-Pipeline doc and video on Youtube, but i still don't know how to use it in right way.

thx in advance

Comment: You can just have `flipcountdown-master` added under `/assets/` since this is a third party library and should be self contained. Now it is up to you how whether it should be referred in `application.js` or used directly.

Comment: Can you show me an example ?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things you can do here:

If you want to utilize the organization structure provided by the asset pipeline plugin, place the .css file in assets/stylesheets directory and the image in the assets/images directory and change any references of `./img/digit-lg.png` to `digit-lg.png` (you could also specify `/assets/digit-lg.png` or `/assets/images/digit-lg.png` and get the same result). Here's what the directory structure should look like:

```
├── assets
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── digit-lg.png
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── jquery.flipcountdown.css
```

The grails asset pipeline ignores the top level images, javascripts, and stylesheets folders when resolving assets, as they are purely for organization purposes.

Or, since this is a third-party stylesheet, it may be best to keep the `.css` file unmodified, and keep things self contained. You can just add the `flipcountdown-master` directory to either the `assets/` directory or `assets/stylesheets/`, keep the css background-image url set to `./img/digit-lg.png` and everything should work fine. Here's the structure in that case:

```
├── assets
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── flipcountdown-master
│           └── img
│               └── digit-lg.png
│           └── jquery.flipcountdown.css
```

The asset pipeline is very flexible to however you feel most comfortable organizing your assets, there isn't only one way to do things. Any file that the pipeline picks up will be eligible for gzip compression.

Comment: You can just add `flipcountdown-master` under `assets` if required.

Comment: Yep, I noted that above, just showed what it would look like if it was placed under the stylesheets directory.

Answer (score 1):

[**Here is the sample app**](https://github.com/dmahapatro/grails-asset-pipeline-flipcountdown).

Particularly look at `application.js` and `application.css` where the external libraries are included.

Just clone the app from github, run-app, and hit the index page. You should see a countdown clock in the index page.

Comment: I commit a "pull request" to master. It's the real project that i want to change the html to gsp pages, however, i failed. I put the original html source code in the folder source_code, can you help me and show me the best practice of using asset-pipeline, because there are just two pages need refactor, dashboard.gsp and the alerts_btns.gsp, there are different js and css files, i think one application.js and one application.css will be huge if i put all together. thx in advance

Comment: Can you come up with an example, at least, fork this sample app's ( one mentioned in answer ) repo and add your sample (with htmls in place)? @beneo

Comment: Yes, i forked the sample app's repo, and the html pages is under https://github.com/beneo/grails-asset-pipeline-flipcountdown/tree/master/source_code

Comment: i don't kown how to contact you, and if there is anything i can do for you, plz free to tell me. THANKS VERY MUCH

Comment: I did not get a chance to look at the app ( working on a framework upgrade ) and hardly get time. Will have a look at the app today once I am done with my ad hoc task. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: Here you go. Follow this latest [commit](https://github.com/dmahapatro/grails-asset-pipeline-flipcountdown/commit/28fb7b7cad67c02652b0608868a5e955eba3e411) in my branch. Fork again or synch with my branch. Take latest changes and run app, you will no longer see any resources error. Look at the latest application.js, application.css and dashboard.gsp for changes. Good Luck & enjoy @beneo :)